# How do I change the JobSettings of a PrinterJob?

Tags: java, javafx, printing

I have this:

```
  public static void print(List<String> lines) {
    TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
    lines.forEach(textArea::appendText);
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();

    JobSettings jobSettings = job.getJobSettings();
    jobSettings.setPrintQuality(PrintQuality.HIGH); // don't know what to do with jobSettings

    Printer printer = job.getPrinter();
    PageLayout pl = printer.createPageLayout(Paper.A4, PageOrientation.PORTRAIT, .10, .10, .25, .25);
    boolean printed = job.printPage(pl, textArea);
    if (printed)
      job.endJob();
  }
```

I'm printing to a thermal printer. The quality is like Draft quality, super low. The printer I'm using is Xprinter XP-58.

I want to change it to High. The JavaFX 8 docs say:

> Applications do not - and cannot - directly create or set a
>   JobSettings instance. One is already installed on the print job when
>   it is created. As documented on PrinterJob, the JobSettings installed
>   on that job will initially reflect the current default settings for
>   the initially associated printer for that job.
>
> The JobSettings delegate then remains the same for the life of the
>   job, and will have it's member properties updated to be compatible
>   with a change in Printer on the job. For example as a result of a user
>   interaction via a platform's dialog. An incompatible setting will
>   usually cause the setting to revert to the default for the new
>   printer.
>
> Any implicit or explicit updates to settings resulting from the user
>   interaction with dialog will be propagated and visible to the
>   application once the user approves the settings by dismissing the
>   dialog using its "accept" option.
>
> For most printing applications it is likely sufficient to let the user
>   set the desired options and have these propagated to the job. For
>   applications which need them, there are setter and getter methods for
>   the individual options, which are also available as properties, and
>   change in values of settings may be monitored and updated via these
>   properties.

In Windows 10 in the Printer Settings of XP-58, I cannot find Printing Quality in Printer Preferences, so I assume that the quality is really bad. But when I print outside of javaFX, the quality is actually very nice and really defined.

Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: Simply setting the state of the `JobSettings` instance should work. If I call [`PrinterJob#showPrintDialog(Window)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/print/PrinterJob.html#showPrintDialog(javafx.stage.Window)) on Windows 10, then click the "Properties" button in the dialog, there's an option for setting the print quality. The properties seem printer-specific. Without doing anything it defaults to "Standard". But if I call `getJobSettings().setPrintQuality(HIGH)` before showing the dialog, it's already set to "High" when I look at it.